# What to do when answerer deletes correct answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I recently asked a question on Stack Overflow and received an answer to it (big surprise, there ;)). During the time that I was reading up on documentation relating to the answer and trying it out, someone (almost definitely the answerer) deleted their answer. Turns out that the answer does in fact work and is cleaner than my own strategy for solving the problem I have. I don't remember the answerer's nick so I don't really have a way of poking them to consider un-deleting it. What do I do now? And what should I generally do when this happens?

In my particular case, one of the commentators here shared an image of the deleted answer => I used the nick there to contact the answerer on chat. They have now un-deleted.

Comment: Get 1500+ more rep, then you can see deleted post. :P

Comment: @nhahtdh, thanks! The answer is correct and has already worked for me. I have no use for the text any more. This question was more from the point of view of: what is best for the *question* and the *community* while being fair to the original answerer.

Comment: @nhahtdh that helped. I got the user's name and pinged them on chat.

Comment: just re-write the answer yourself and post it. There's no real reason to wait for the original answerer to do it if they've already deleted it and moved on.

Comment: Undelete *♦* it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is not a lot you can do other than finding someone with 10k+ reputation whose prepared to take a screenshot of the deleted answer.

While SE has the right to use your content, it's still your content so you can always<sup>(*)</sup> delete it or have it disassociated from your account.

You need some way of indicating that the answer *might* be useful to deter the poster from deleting it if they were thinking that it wasn't. I can understand why you wouldn't want to up-vote it without trying it out, but there's not a lot else you can do. Part of me wants to suggest that you leave a comment along the lines of:

> This looks promising, I'm just checking it out

but I fear that it would be flagged as "too chatty" by many people.

<sup>* There are well documented restrictions on deleting questions</sup>

Comment: Correct. nhahtdh's screenshot helped. I pinged the user on chat asking them to consider un-deleting it. I guess if they don't within the next week or so, I'll just post the same answer myself.

Comment: I suggest asking why they deleted it. There may be some serious but non-obvious problem with the answer that they realized after posting it.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - but without another post by the same author you can't do that.

Comment: @ChrisF I realize that SO's lack of facilities for communication between users is a problem in this sort of situation. I'm hoping that, despite SO's clunkiness, the OP does manage to establish communication and so can ask.

Comment: Lack of communication causes this problem, yes.  No voting and no comments for a day or two might well leave the impression that maintaining the answer for years to come isn't worth the hassle.

Comment: This would be a great use case for [self destructing comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179069/how-appropriate-are-self-destruct-comments)

Comment: +1 - often there are question that look one way at first glance and I'd answer, than read question couple times/see comments and find that my answer is not really related to the question *as asked* or simply not exactly correct - it is often feels more producive to delete question so other people can answer rather than fixing one up. Please, please, please comment/react in some way if you see promising answers.