# A curious case of the deleted answer being the right answer and all other answers being useless

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51700002/14768) problem to happen to me without Jenkins and where rebuilding the local tree was not appropriate. I started to ask a new question after my Google-fu found nothing, and halfway through typing the question this question popped up as the top suggested result.

It was, but the accepted answer is useless. However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68755001/14768) -1 deleted answer was the correct answer. I could certainly improve the answer to explain why it works, but it will still be a -1 deleted answer.

Comment: Yes but you can then also vote to undelete, no?

Comment: You could also post an answer yourself, and attribute the deleted answer.

Comment: @Gimby: It's deleted by post author. I hesitate.

Comment: @Joshua Then I certainly backup cigien's suggestion. The only reason you can see that deleted answer is because of your respectable reputation anyway, for all intents and purposes the deleted answer does not exist.

Comment: @cigien: Whelp cigen go ahead and write that as answer because that's what I'm going to do.

Comment: There seems to be another question asking the same thing. There is a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272215/what-to-do-when-answerer-deletes-correct-answer?rq=1#comment98559_272215) on that question suggesting to post an answer, but someone should post an answer saying that.

Comment: The mere fact that the poster deleted it doesn't mean that we can't vote to undelete it. Posting any content here gives Stack Exchange the right to distribute the content. My understanding is that that applies to answers too. If the community feels that the content is useful, we have the right to vote to undelete it.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica: I was wondering if that might be the case but really wanted another set of eyes first.

Comment: Of course it is the case but we also don't have to be obtuse about it. The running advice is that if existing answers are not good enough, you should post your own better one. I'd much prefer a new better answer than undeleting a downvoted one which will need improving, given the choice.